# Using ArrayList.size() to create unique Id's

Tags: java

An Employee has the attributes `name`, `Id` and `Password`

I have stored a ArrayList of `Employees` in a `Shop` class, whenever I create a new Employee I find the size of the list of Employees ArrayList and assign that number as their Id.

It works fine but of course when I start adding or deleting Employees the Employee Id's will start indexing off.

One way I though of fixing this is by sorting the array by Id.

Is their a better way of generating Id based on when they are added to a list?

This is for practice for myself not in anyway for use in the real world

```
public void addHiredEmployee() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
        String nameEmployee = kb.nextLine();

        //Creating the Employee Id
        int employeeID = listEmployee.size();

        System.out.println("Enter password");
        String employeePassword = kb.nextLine();

        Employee employeeHired = new Employee(nameEmployee, employeeID, employeePassword);

        listEmployee.add(employeeHired);

        kb.close();

        listEmployee.toString();
    }
```

Comment: You can create hash based on the `name` or `id` of an employee, or take the creation date and time (of the employee) from the system as an id

Comment: I would just add an `int` maybe called `lastUsedId` or `nextUnusedId` to the class holding `listEmployee` and just increase it by one if you add a new one.

Comment: You can use always the max of the employee id + 1. Or you can also use an uniqueId or an calculated hash that makes each employId unique always.

Comment: Im not sure about hash based ill look it up

Comment: I meant to put + 1 in their but this will throw the indexing off and if I delete id = 1 and there are 10 Employees in the list and I add one a new employee I will have two id = 10!

Comment: If you are ever going to remove employees from the list, the `.size()` will not give you unique IDs, regardless of what order you keep the list in. You should not generally reuse an ID even if the object which had that ID is deleted; some other object (e.g. a payslip) could still use the old ID in some way, in which case the program state would become corrupted. I would recommend using `++lastID` or `nextID++` to choose the first number which hasn't been used so far.

Comment: take a lok at this http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Comment: @kaya3: So should I scrap this idea totally and just create a random id using letters and numbers ...? Then check each employee's id against the random id?

Comment: You can use a separate counter variable like `lastID` or `nextID` and increment it each time, to ensure uniqueness. Using random IDs doesn't guarantee uniqueness, though you can make the ID long enough so that collisions are extremely unlikely.

Comment: @ user6092942: That is a cool article thanks :)

Comment: @kaya3: Thanks I do not understand how the next and last would be implemented, Have you seen the above article I might use the UUID